# phpMyAdmin - manually import csv and skip columns

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin, in the tab `import`, how to specify which columns of the csv must be skipped by the import?

For example, I have this csv:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
a       b       c       x       0
1       2       3       y       1
```

I need to **manually** import that csv skipping the 4th column.

With the `Csv using LOAD DATA` I can specify the `Column names`; in that field I tried to insert these but without working:

```
col1, col2, col3, @dummy, col5
```

> Invalid column (@dummy) specified! Ensure that columns names are spelled correctly, separated by commas, and not enclosed in quotes.

and

```
col1, col2, col3, , col5
```

> SQL query:
>
> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/phpBlaBlaBla' 
>   INTO TABLE `tblName` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
>   (`col1` , `col2` , `col3` , , `col5`)
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `col5`)' at line 1

The phpMyAdmin version is `4.0.10.16`.

Thanks in advance!